# Storyboard not getting updated

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'm testing an update of an application i've been working on.

The problem is, when i have the older version of the application installed and i install the new one, the storyboard doesn't seem to update to the last version. When i try to initialise a ViewController with the StoryboardID it doesn't find it, but, if i use the older StoryboardID it actually finds it correctly.

I don't know if i am missing something of how storyboard work or any specially consideration i have to take when updating an application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was related to localisation stuff. I removed my base localisation and started using the english one, this solved the issue.